# Reading fixed width strings with numpy.fromfile

Tags: python, numpy, binary-data

I have a binary file, that has the structure:

```
int32, <8-byte string>, 
int32, <8-byte string>,
int32, <8-byte string>,
.....
```

I would like to read it using `np.fromfile` (rather than line-by-line), since it's a very big file. I can create a custom data type like this:

```
myDatatype = np.dtype([('mynumber', np.int32), ('mystring', np.byte, 8)])
```

and then read it using:

```
data = np.fromfile(f, myDatatype)
```

The disadvantage is, that now data has a byte-array instead of a string. Is there a way use `np.fromfile`, so that it directly loads into a string-type?

Comment: How about 'S8' for the string field?